# How can I list all of the pages that display a certain view?

Tags: 7, views

In Drupal 7, is there a way either programmatically or through the UI to generate a list of all of the pages that display a particular view?

Comment: What do you mean by "instances"? The number of displays?

Comment: Yes, the number of times the view is used.

Comment: @clive and the pages that view is displayed on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this through the UI and even to do it programmatically would be a tall order. Views can contain page, block, panel pane, and other types of display. Those displays can be embedded in pages via blocks, panels, or custom code.

If you have a specific view display in mind, e.g. a block, it would narrow the scope of the task, but the task would still be very difficult.